# I want to convert this Metical query to SQL Server 2005 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
DELETE FROM rpt62_attribution_value
WHERE  elo_id NOT IN(SELECT elo_id
                     FROM   (SELECT elo_id,
                                    elo_value,
                                    attr_value,
                                    ilo_flag,
                                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY elo_value,
                                    attr_value ORDER BY
                                    elo_id)
                                            Rank
                             FROM   rpt62_attribution_value) tmp
                     WHERE  rank = 1
                     ORDER  BY 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

To make this a valid query in SQL Server simply remove the `ORDER  BY 1` as this is disallowed in subqueries and derived tables except if `TOP` is specified and serves no function.

However it looks like you are removing duplicates so something like this may well be better

```
;WITH T AS
(                     
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY elo_value, attr_value 
                              ORDER BY elo_id) [Rank]
 FROM   rpt62_attribution_value    
 )
 DELETE FROM T WHERE [Rank] > 1
```